# What does pre/post modification mean in Airbus MPD?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, terminology, airbus

What is the difference between POST MOD (with partial mod i.e SXXXX) and PRE MOD (with partial mod) in the applicability column of an Airbus MPD (Maintenance Planning Document)?

Answer (score 1):

It means that operator have to check what status of the particular MOD have the subject A/C, pre or post. Therefore it affects operators MP.

Answer (score 0):

"Post Mod" means the modification issued by the manufacturer was carried out on an aircraft, and "Pre Modification" has the opposite meaning.